# How to securely store user credentials from external website

Tags: architecture, security, web-services

I'm developing an application where I'd like to use credentials from external websites. This will be used to login with the website API and get information for the user.

Example: I want to use the user Reddit's account to warn him if more than X people reply to one of his comment.

How would I go about storing the user's Reddit credentials on my end securely so I only ask once and can automate this process. Or is that even possible?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/please-give-us-your-email-password.html

Comment: Totally agree. I'll stick to services that provide OAuth access.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store a user's login credentials to a third-party service. Instead, reddit provides an oAuth API to acquire access to parts of the website that require user authentication. See: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth.